# boolean c-string sequence - reporting a match

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, boolean, sequence

if i have a boolean prototype, such as `bool repeat(const char *S, char *P)`
and I want to search S for the same sequence as P, & return true if there is a match, for example:

```
char *this = "ABCDEFGH";
bool found;
found = count(this, "DEF"); // will be true
found = count(this, "FED"); // will be false
```

My current naive solution is

```
bool count (const char *S, char *P){
bool found;
int i = 0;
if (S[0] = P[0] && S[1] = P[1] && S[2] = P[2]) found = true;
else i + 1;
```

can i use the syntax S[0 + i] and so on to continue to look in the array if the first member is not a match?

Any insight is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: `char *this = "ABCDEFGH";`? Is that even legal?

Comment: @IInspectable Yes it is. See [this post.](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/249554/assigning-strings-to-pointer-in-c)

Comment: @AhmedAkhtar: This question is about [tag:c++], though, and `this` is a reserved keyword.

Comment: @IInspectable Yeah you are right.

Comment: @Lucas look at my answer I have posted tried and tested working code.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you have to change the condition

```
if (S[0] = P[0] && S[1] = P[1] && S[2] = P[2])
```

to this

```
if (S[0] == P[0] && S[1] == P[1] && S[2] == P[2])
```

Because you are not using the equality operator in the first one. It is assignment operator, does not return true or false. Just assigns the second object's value to first one's.

If you're only searching 'size of 3 array' in the second one, this code will work after fixing the equality operator.

Answer (score 1):

This is C++, and as such you can use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string). Using `std::string` has multiple advantages.

One of them is the built-in [`std::string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) method, which you can use to see if a string contains another one:

```
bool search(const std::string& S, const std::string& P)
{
    return S.find(P) != std::string::npos;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly use `==` for comparison instead of `=`, which is for assignment.

Secondly dont use `this` as a variable name because it is a reserved keyword.

Thirdly, for such matching you need to loop through both the `char` arrays, and for that you first need to find their sizes.

Since strings in c are `'\0'` terminated, use the [`strlen`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/) function of `string.h` to find the size of a string.

```
#include <string.h>
bool count (const char *S, char *P)
{
 int sizeS = strlen(S);
 int sizeP = strlen(P);

 bool found = false;

 int i,j;

 for(i = 0; i < sizeS; i++)
 {
  if (S[i] == P[0])// step1: find first character of P in S
  {
   for(j = 1; j < sizeP; j++)// step2: first has matched, look for the rest
   {
    if(S[i+j] != P[j])// if any of the rest does not match, go on to step1
    {
     break;
    }
   }
   if(j == sizeP)// if all matched, j's loop did not break
   {
    found = true;
    break;
   }
  }
 }
 return found;
}
```

Note: I have tried this code to work.

Comment: `S` and `P` aren't arrays. They are pointers. The expression `sizeof(S)/sizeof(S[0])` does not return the array size (or string length). Besides, the `sizeof` operator returns a constant of type `std::size_t`, not `int`.